# Gunicorn - exits the terminal automatically immediatly after running venv

Tags: python, virtualenv, gunicorn, falconframework

When I run my gunicorn command in python venv, the terminal gets closed abruptly, without giving any message or error.

It is a sample python falcon api. I am able to run the api if I am not using the venv.

The command used for running gunicorn:

`exec bin/gunicorn sample_api:api -b 8080`

Is there something to be taken care when we are running gunicorn app using venv.

Comment: Try without `exec`!

Comment: @KlausD. It works. Can you write it as the answer?